# How to check if a wagtail block contains given text

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a wagtail/django template that contains

```
{% for block in page.content %}
    {% include_block block %}
    {% if "Email address:" in block %}
        This is an email address
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The block does contain the text, but the if clause does not return True

What is wrong?

Comment: You can store the content in a variable, so with `{% include_block block as text_block %}` and then check with `{% if 'Email address:' in text_block %}`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks. That gives the error "Unexpected argument to 'include_block' tag: 'as'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{% if "Email address:" in block %}` should be: `{% if "Email address:" in block.value %}`.

The block object you get from looping over `page.content` is not a simple string - it contains properties such as `block_type` and methods to allow it to be rendered as HTML - as a result, string comparisons like `in` won't work directly on that object.

Depending on what block types you have defined, you may also need a check like `{% if block.block_type == 'text' %}` to make sure you're not doing the string comparison on a non-string-based block (such as a StructBlock).